My Azure AD B2C User Flow is not returning a token on jwt.ms
I have recently created a new Azure Ad B2C service and have linked a tenant to that service. I am attempting to create user flows on the service, and when testing my sign in/sign up user flow, I had it set up to redirect to https://jwt.ms so I can see the token info. After doing a test and signing up, it redirects me to jwt.ms but there is no token displayed. Both the "Enter token below" field as well as the Decoded Token and Claims sections are blank. When setting up the user attributes for the user flow, I made sure to check the "collect attribute" and "return claim" boxes for Country/Region and Surname. I also checked the boxes for a couple more "collect attribute". Those were Given Name and Display Name.
Blank Token

If you configure an app with https://jwt.ms for testing, you need to enable the implicit grant flow:

